# Export list of files (and folder structure) to a file (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, file, export, file-listing

Is there a quick way to list all files in a folder and send that list to a text or csv file? In addition to the files in the current folder, I want to include files in subfolders (nested) and I want the list to include relative path information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options depending on what you are looking for.

Run the commands from a command prompt in the topmost folder.

tree > OutputFile.txt

Or

dir /s > OutputFile.txt